# In general, how to convert ilasm syntax into Reflection.Emit calls?

Tags: .net, reflection.emit, cil, ildasm

I am writing a special-purpose mini-compiler and I often view disassembled CIL to figure out how to do things. But it's often not obvious how to translate the disassembled code to Reflection.Emit calls. Does a reference manual exist or any other source of information for doing this translation?

**Edit**: yes, mapping the opcodes to ILGenerator is pretty straightforward; I'm talking about all the other stuff like the .directives and attributes. For instance, how do you find out how to write the Reflection.Emit equivalent of something like `Dictionary<TKey,TValue>`?

```
.class public auto ansi serializable beforefieldinit Dictionary<TKey, TValue>
    extends System.Object
    implements System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2<!TKey, !TValue>,
    System.Collections.Generic.ICollection`1<valuetype 
        System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair`2<!TKey, !TValue>>, 
    ...
{
    .custom instance void System.Diagnostics.DebuggerDisplayAttribute::
        .ctor(string) = { string('Count = {Count}') }

    .method public hidebysig newslot virtual final instance bool TryGetValue
        (!TKey key, [out] !TValue& 'value') cil managed
    {
        .maxstack 3
        .locals init ([0] int32 num)
        ...
```

Or how about the "param" directive?

```
// public static void SayHello(string s = "Hello World!")
.method public hidebysig static void SayHello([opt] string s) cil managed
{
    .param [1] = "Hello World!"
```

Comment: Isn't the OpCodes class a one to one mapping? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.aspx

Comment: Depending upon what you're doing, it's a lot easier to use expression trees, which you can then compile to CIL: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397951.aspx

Comment: Expression trees are concerned mainly with building expressions, not with building the metadata of classes and methods. I asked this question because I want to know how to generate the latter. (I'm not using .NET 4 yet but I heard Expression Trees have been extended somewhat in .NET 4).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since no one could answer the question, I conclude no documentation exists to show the relationship between ilasm syntax and Reflection.Emit calls.

As a side note, I've found that it's usually better to create code at run-time using [RunSharp](http://sourceforge.net/projects/runsharp/files/) than Reflection.Emit. When I have time I'll try to figure out the new version of [Cecil](http://www.mono-project.com/Cecil).

Comment: +1, good to know about RunSharp.  In your exp, how mature it is?  Can it generate a full set of objects & CIL for .NET (which version?)  There seems to be a lack of ongoing development.

Comment: I don't think it's actively developed but I was able to talk to the developer. I don't think it's feature-complete enough for use in a compiler, but it can generate types, constructors, fields, methods, events, custom attributes, methods, and expressions. I think I gave the wrong website link; it should be http://code.google.com/p/runsharp/

Answer (score 4):

I would use the [EmitHelper component](http://www.bltoolkit.net/Doc.EmitHelloWorld.ashx) of the [BLToolkit](http://www.bltoolkit.net) for that purpose.  It provides a fluent API resembling IL code, wrapping Reflection.Emit.  Example extracted from the linked article:

```
EmitHelper emit = new AssemblyBuilderHelper("HelloWorld.dll")
    .DefineType  ("Hello", typeof(object), typeof(IHello))
    .DefineMethod(typeof(IHello).GetMethod("SayHello"))
    .Emitter;
emit
    // string.Format("Hello, {0}!", toWhom)
    //
    .ldstr   ("Hello, {0}!")
    .ldarg_1
    .call    (typeof(string), "Format", typeof(string), typeof(object))

    // Console.WriteLine("Hello, World!");
    //
    .call    (typeof(Console), "WriteLine", typeof(string))
    .ret();

Type type = emit.Method.Type.Create();
```

Answer (score 1):

You are looking at the IL for the System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<> class.  The "Dictionary" class name is the string you pass to ModuleBuilder.DefineType().

The .param attribute is generated in C# version 4 or VB.NET for parameters that have a default value.  You set it with the ParameterBuilder you get back from MethodBuilder.DefineParameter().  Use the SetConstant() method.